# Java JAR properties

Tags: java, jar, properties, executable

Пытаюсь перезаписать properties, в IDE все получается, а в jar вылетает исключение:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: main.properties
>    (Не удается найти указанный файл)
>         at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>         at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>         at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
>         at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
>         at main.Main.main(Main.java:20)
> ```

Код:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("main.properties"));
System.out.println(properties.toString());
properties.setProperty("adasd","1111");
System.out.println(properties.toString());
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("main.properties");
properties.store(fileOutputStream," ");
System.out.println(properties.values());
```

Comment: Естественно, после упаковки в jar, main.properties больше не существует как отдельный файл, теперь это часть архива. Обращайтесь к нему как к ресурсу.

Comment: да но ведь ресурс можно только читать, а мне нужно в нем хранить конфигурации и периодически вносить изменения

Comment: Тогда вам придётся искать иное хранилище, не упакованное.